# Regex for wildcard char (*) search

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex which can have a wild card char(*) at the start or the end of the string , but not in between the other characters.At most one * is allowed. There can be any number of other chars.

**List of Valid Inputs:**

```
*
A*
*A
AB*
*AB
A
AB
ABC
1
*1
1*

*12
12*
123
```

**List of invalid inputs:**

```
**
A**
**A
A*A
*A*
*AB*
*A*B*
1**
**2
*1*
*1*2
```

I came up with the following regex

```
^(?!(?:.*\*){2})[a-zA-Z0-9*]+$
```

It works for all the conditions except A*A . I am trying to fix it but haven't been successful. Please help to fix this.

Comment: `^(?!.*\*\*)[a-zA-Z0-9,\s*]+$`? See https://regex101.com/r/jE0txh/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  - Your regex matches expressions like - A*A , *A* which are part of invalid inputs. Can you help me to fix that?

Comment: `(^\*?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]*\*?$)`... try with this

Comment: Ah, your sample strings should be written with a newline, not with commas, right? Just add `(?!.*\b\*\b)` lookahead, `^(?!(?:.*\*){2})(?!.*\b\*\b)[*a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: @ GolamMazid Sajib , @ Wiktor Stribiżew The expressions both of your mentioned above are working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invalidate any input where `*` appears in between letters, you may add a `(?!.*\b\*\b)` lookahead. The `\b\*\b` pattern matches a `*` in between word chars (letters, digits or `_`).

Thus, you may use

```
^(?!(?:.*\*){2})(?!.*\b\*\b)[*a-zA-Z0-9]+$
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jE0txh/3)

Note you may make it more efficient if you use  the principle of contrast with your first lookahead pattern (if you need to test it online, remember to add `\n`, `[^*\n]`, since you test against a single multiline string there, not against multiple strings):

```
^(?!(?:[^*]*\*){2})(?!.*\b\*\b)[*a-zA-Z0-9]+$
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:.*\*){2})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are two occurrences of any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then `*` immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?!.*\b\*\b)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then `*` enclosed with word characters immediately to the right of the current location
- `[*a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ ASCII alphanumeric chars or `*`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This works perfectly as expected .Thanks for the explanation..!!